# How to use docker-compose on ovh hosting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, ovh

I'm still not able to properly run docker-compose in my OVH VPS.

I'm developing a small nodeJS application using mongodb. My configuration works on my PC (Windows 7), but when I push it on my VPS the result is not as expected.

**My docker-compose.yml**

```
db:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  command: "--smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null"
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    PORT: 3000
```

**My Dockerfile (for the nodeJS part)**

```
FROM node:onbuild

WORKDIR /app

ADD package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install && npm ls
RUN mv /app/node_modules /node_modules

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

**My nodeJS server**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var express = require('express');

var MONGO_DB;
var DOCKER_DB = process.env.DB_PORT;
if ( DOCKER_DB ) {
  MONGO_DB = DOCKER_DB.replace( 'tcp', 'mongodb' ) + '/app';
} else {
  MONGO_DB = process.env.MONGODB;
}
var retry = 0;

mongoose.connect(MONGO_DB);



const app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello world\n');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

**The docker version on my server (Ubuntu 14.04)**

```
Client:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:30:23 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:30:23 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**When I run:**

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

All works fine, but at the end only the mongo container is running and the NodeJS is stopped.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution ! 
**MyDockerfile** looks like this

```
FROM node:onbuild

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

And the **docker-compose.yml**

```
db:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

All works fine right now :)

Comment: That help, has same problem.... It looks like problem with path `- .:/app`

Answer (score 2):

is your `server.js` file on the same directory as the `Dockerfile`? I think the problem is that server.js has to also be in `WORKDIR`. And also I think you're copying your code to the container on this one, use `CP` instead of `RUN mv`. Try this:

```
FROM node:onbuild

WORKDIR /app

ADD package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install && npm ls
COPY /app/node_modules /node_modules

ADD server.js /app/server.js # add this line

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

updated it: I incorrectly wrote CP instead of the correct COPY, Sorry :(

Comment: I tried your solution, but the result is still the same. The "CP" command was not found, so I kept the older line.

Comment: sorry, its supposed to be COPY not CP, I updated my answer, my bad

Comment: I tried with COPY and it fails too. Basically docker-compose is not installed on OVH's VPS. Even if it's possible to install it, maybe we can't use it... furthermore I found some tutorials provided by OVH and it explains How to set up three containers without docker-compose.

Comment: oh, I thought you ran docker-compose on ovh,